# building pandas dynamic structure

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am building a Pandas data frame with samples which contains dynamic structure. I have statics features that always shows up in every sample, and dynamic group of features (events with static features) which can vary over the considered samples.

I will show you one database example with 5 samples:

> - Individual 1: SF E1
> - Individual 2: SF E1 E2 E3
> - Individual 3: SF E1 E2 E3 E4
> - Individual 4: SF E1 E2 E3 E4 E5 E6
> - Individual 5: SF E1 E2 E3

where

- SF: Static Features
- Ei: Event #i

The events contains static features (does not vary over the rest of the events). So, let's say that an Event contains 3 features then the dataset looks like the following:

> - Individual 1: SF  E1F1 E2F2 E1F3
> - Individual 2: SF  E1F1 E2F2 E1F3 E2F1 E2F2 E2F3 E3F1 E3F2 E3F3
> - Individual 3: ... (same analogy)
> - Individual 4: ... (same analogy)
> - Individual 5: ... (same analogy)

Is there a way that Pandas manage this situation? Could pandas handle nested data frames?

I was thinking to take the maximum number of events of all the individuals (samples) and imputing the missing data with an algorithm. I appreciate some help

Comment: question is unrelated to `machine-learning` and `scikit-learn` - kindly do not spam the tags (removed)

Comment: Did you try hierarchical index https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex

Comment: @sathyz that would work, but still doesn't solve the problem to have different row length.. (some individuals would have 4 events, others 8 and so forth..). My aim is to build a fixed data frame (rows: #patients, columns: #features) then the #features should be the same for each individual. The only thing I can think about is to create missing data columns and then imputing it using MICE or other imputing algorithm..